# Adding a background image in VB script to an asp page

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to add a background image inside a div tag in vb script on an asp page but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
 <div style=""background-image:url('background1.png' );""></div>
```

It doesn't work - the image does not appear although the rest of the page loads correctly

This does work.. but I need the image to be in a div tag, not an image tag:

```
<img src='background1.png'></img>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have two pairs of quotes instead of one?  You tag this question as asp-classic and vbscript but only show us HTML why are these tags significant?  Is there in fact more to your code that you haven't shown us?

Comment: If the image is dynamic and you don't know its dimensions, you can use JavaScript to resize the div properly. Let me know if relevant.

Answer (score 3):

A DIV with a background image has no clue how big the image is. You need to give it a width and height.